# Why Is FluentNHibernate Missing CascadeType.REPLICATE?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I must keep the same domain running at two places at the same time. One end must be able to run "offline", while still must receive and send data to the other end from time to time when "online". Basically we got a central server which aggregates data comming from the clients and serves some updated data (like the latest price of a product, new products, etc). I'm using NHibernate to take care of persistance.

I'm trying to use NHibernate's `Replicate` method

```
session.Replicate(detached, ReplicationMode.LatestVersion);
```

to get the object comming from the other end and incorporate/merge/attach to the "local" database.

It fails to execute because **it can't cascade the references and collections**. Reviewing the cascade options from FluentNHibernate (<strike>and even directly looking at NHibernate source code</strike>) I could not find the REPLICATE cascade type. From Hibernate's documentation:
[CascadeType.REPLICATE](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/CascadeType.html#REPLICATE)

My question is: *does anybody knows why FluentNHibernate is missing such option?* Is there a different/better way to set this kind of cascade behaviour?

I tried the `Cascade.Merge()` option together with `session.Merge(detached)`, but although the cascade works just fine, it give me some headaches, mainly because of the id generation and optmistic lock (versioning).

EDIT: NHibernate's source code DOES have a `ReplicateCascadeStyle` class that maps to the string "replicate". The `Cascade` / `CascadeConverter` classes (from Mapping.ByCode namespace) DOES NOT have Replicate as an option. So NHibernate itself supports cascade on Replicate, but only through manual mapping I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, as I'm using Fluent NHibernate to map about 100+ classes, switch to xml mapping is not an option to me.
So I forked Fluent NHibernate on GitHub, added the missing Cascade.Replicate option and sent a [pull request](https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/pull/243).

Hope it helps someone.